# unresolved external symbol, having trouble trying to fix

Tags: c++

Hello I am getting this error from my code below:

`Error 4 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Noun::Noun(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??0Noun@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Dictionary::Dictionary(void)" (??0Dictionary@@QAE@XZ)`

I guess this error is from no declaring the constructor `Noun(string word, string definition);` I am also unsure how I can declare this to remove the error so I can compile my code. Below is my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker complains that you have not added a **definition** for the constructor of `Noun`. Add it and this error will be fixed. I believe you only mean to call the parent's constructor in it so maybe this will do the job:

```
Noun(string word, string definition) : Word(word, definition) {}
```

Comment: Im confused where to add this...?

Comment: @user2881555 replace the line where you declare the constructor of line with this line. It will do you good to lookup method declaration and definition and also constructor declaration/defintion in google.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the constructor

```
Noun(string word, string definition)
```

exactly the way as you did it with the constructor of the class `Word`.
But you need to make sure that the definition of Noun is known when you use it. Normaly, one uses a separate header file for this. The content of the header-file for class `Noun` is already contained in the code you gave: It starts with

```
class Noun : public virtual Word {
```

and ends with

```
};
```

Move that to a header-file named noun.h and include that in your cpp-file via

```
#include "noun.h"
```